# Increment inside while loop between 1 and 0 by .1 why is variable val not reversing at 1?

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, floating-point

```
tweeninc=0.0
tranVal=0.0
increment=1
tweenVal=0.0
increment1=0.1
while True:



    if tweenVal==1.0:
        increment1=-0.1
    if tweenVal==0.0:
        increment1=0.1
    if tranVal==14:
        increment=-1
    if tranVal==-14:
        increment=1
    tranVal=tranVal+increment
    tweenVal=tweenVal+increment1

    print tweenVal
```

inside the while loop why does the tweenVal keep going beyond 1.

it goes .8,.9,1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3...1.9... and I want it to go .8,.9,1.0,.9,.8,.7...0,.1,.2

Im doing the same thing for the value under it which goes between -14 and 14 does it have something to do with it being a floating point?

Comment: I suggest you change one of your tags to a language tag.

Comment: thanks will people still see this question because it isn't "new"

Comment: It is still visible to all. Also, I do think your problem lies with the normal floating point problems. Try to introduce a variance variable (something like 0.0001) and if the tweenVal is within that variance of your target, then do your operation.

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate. There are lots of questions on Stack Overflow about why floating-point calculations give unexpected results. Here is one: [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2):

Floating point encoding is imprecise and can not represent all possible values. What you think of as `0.1` is actually `0.10000000149011612` when [converted to double precision ieee754 format](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html). Bottom line -- do not do exact comparisons on floating point values.

Something like this should work better:

```
if tweenVal > 0.95:
    increment1=-0.1
if tweenVal < 0.05:
    increment1=0.1
```